# How clear the validation for the selection box?

Tags: jquery, validation, selection

My problem now is the validation for the selection box will come out after I click the NEXT button when the user didn't choose any one of the selection,but then if I click more times on the NEXT button,the validation kept out come out.

In my page,there are consist of one selection box and one input field,the validation for input field just appear once no matter I click several times of the NEXT button,but the selection box didn't.

Can somebody help me?

Here is my code:

```js
$('#btnNextContactInfoModel').off('click').click(function() {
  var focusSet = false;
  if (!$('#contact123').val() || !$('#contacttype').val()) {
    if ($("#contact123").parent().next(".validation").length == 0) // only add if not added
    {
      $("#contact123").parent().after("<div class='validation' style='color:red;margin-bottom: 20px;'>This field is required.</div>");
    }
    if ($("#contacttype").parent().next(".validation").value == undefined) // only add if not added
    {
      $("#contacttype").after("<div class='validation' style='color:red;margin-bottom: 20px;'>This field is required.</div>");
    }

    e.preventDefault(); // prevent form from POST to server
    $('#contact123').focus();
    $('#contacttype').focus();
    focusSet = true;
  } else {
    $("#contact123").parent().next(".validation").remove();
    $("#contacttype").parent().before(".validation").remove(); // remove it
  }

  $("#contactInfoModel").closeModal();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div id="selectcontacttype" class="input-field col s12 m3 l3">
    <select id="contacttype" name="contactselection">
      <option value="" disabled selected>Please select</option>
      <option value="1">Type 1</option>
      <option value="2">Type 2</option>
      <option value="3">Type 3</option>
      <option value="4">Type 4</option>
      <option value="5">Type 5</option>
    </select>
    <label data-i18n="personal-particular-update.msg_type"></label>
  </div>
  <div class="input-field col s12 m3 l3">
    <label class="active" for="ContactInfo">Contact Info</label>
    <div id="Contact Info">
      <input id="contact123" name="contactsTypes" type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" id="storeType" />
  <input type="hidden" id="storecontactinfo" />
</div>

<div class="modal-footer">
  <button id="btnNextContactInfoModel" class="btn-large btn-form-2 btn-floating waves-effect waves-light blue darken-2 right" type="button">
    NEXT
  </button>
  <button id="btnCloseContactInfoModel" class="btn-large btn-form-2 btn-floating waves-effect waves-light red darken-2 left" type="button">
    Close
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer..
I have just added a length of the validation , if length is 0 then the validation message is added, otherwise message will not be added.

```
$('#btnNextContactInfoModel').off('click').click(function() {
  var focusSet = false;
  if (!$('#contact123').val() || !$('#contacttype').val()) {
    if ($("#contact123").parent().next(".validation").length == 0) // only add if not added
    {
      $("#contact123").parent().after("<div class='validation' style='color:red;margin-bottom: 20px;'>This field is required.</div>");
    }
    if ($("#contacttype").parent().find(".validation").value == undefined && $("#contacttype").parent().find(".validation").length == 0) // only add if not added
    {
    debugger;
      $("#contacttype").after("<div class='validation' style='color:red;margin-bottom: 20px;'>This field is required.</div>");
    }

    e.preventDefault(); // prevent form from POST to server
    $('#contact123').focus();
    $('#contacttype').focus();
    focusSet = true;
  } else {
    $("#contact123").parent().next(".validation").remove();
    $("#contacttype").parent().before(".validation").remove(); // remove it
  }

  $("#contactInfoModel").closeModal();
})
```

Here is jsFiddle link : [click here](https://jsfiddle.net/w43dmdh7/)

Comment: Can I know how to just appear the validation for the input field only if the user already choose either one of the selection?And if the user write the answer in the input field ady,when they click the Next button,the validation will only appear in the selection there but not both

Answer (score 0):

You just forgot a .parent() when happening the message below $('#contacttype') :

```js
$('#btnNextContactInfoModel').off('click').click(function() {
  var focusSet = false;
  if (!$('#contact123').val() || !$('#contacttype').val()) {
    if ($("#contact123").parent().next(".validation").length == 0) // only add if not added
    {
      $("#contact123").parent().after("<div class='validation' style='color:red;margin-bottom: 20px;'>This field is required.</div>");
    }
    if ($("#contacttype").parent().next(".validation").length == 0) // only add if not added
    {
      $("#contacttype").parent().after("<div class='validation' style='color:red;margin-bottom: 20px;'>This field is required.</div>");
    }

    e.preventDefault(); // prevent form from POST to server
    $('#contact123').focus();
    $('#contacttype').focus();
    focusSet = true;
  } else {
    $("#contact123").parent().next(".validation").remove();
    $("#contacttype").parent().next(".validation").remove(); // remove it
  }

  $("#contactInfoModel").closeModal();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div id="selectcontacttype" class="input-field col s12 m3 l3">
    <select id="contacttype" name="contactselection">
      <option value="" disabled selected>Please select</option>
      <option value="1">Type 1</option>
      <option value="2">Type 2</option>
      <option value="3">Type 3</option>
      <option value="4">Type 4</option>
      <option value="5">Type 5</option>
    </select>
    <label data-i18n="personal-particular-update.msg_type"></label>
  </div>
  <div class="input-field col s12 m3 l3">
    <label class="active" for="ContactInfo">Contact Info</label>
    <div id="Contact Info">
      <input id="contact123" name="contactsTypes" type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" id="storeType" />
  <input type="hidden" id="storecontactinfo" />
</div>

<div class="modal-footer">
  <button id="btnNextContactInfoModel" class="btn-large btn-form-2 btn-floating waves-effect waves-light blue darken-2 right" type="button">
    NEXT
  </button>
  <button id="btnCloseContactInfoModel" class="btn-large btn-form-2 btn-floating waves-effect waves-light red darken-2 left" type="button">
    Close
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Can I know how to just appear the validation for the input field only if the user already choose either one of the selection?And if the user write the answer in the input field ady,when they click the Next button,the validation will only appear in the selection there but not both